# indexing with eledmac and eledpar

Tags: indexing, eledmac

Using eledmac and eledpar for typesetting a critical edition, I wanted to make a splitted index with the `\edindex[]{}` command. Although I think, that packages are loaded in the correct order and the syntax of \edindex is correct, latex returns the folowing error message:

```
./test2.tex:36: Undefined control sequence.`
<argument> \string \indexentry {\@index@txt 
                                            \@edindex@hyperref }{\thepageline }
l.36 ...iae Iovis\edindex[persons]{Manubiae Iovis}
                                                   tres creduntur esse, quar...
```

The following MWE produces this error. I'd be grateful for any hint on whats wrong with the source.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[ngerman,latin]{babel}

%\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{0.725\baselineskip plus 0.115\baselineskip minus 0.192\baselineskip}}

\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}

\footparagraph{A}
\footparagraph{B}
\footparagraph{C}
%\makeindex[title=Index,columns=2]
\newcommand{\AAp}[4]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\Afootnote{#3 \textit{#4}}}}
\newcommand{\BAp}[4]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\Bfootnote{#3 \textit{#4}}}}
\newcommand{\CAp}[4]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\Cfootnote{#3 \textit{#4}}}}

\makeindex[title=Allgemeinindex,columns=2]{}
\makeindex[name=persons, title=Index of names,columns=2]{}

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledchapter*{blabla}
\pend\pstart
Manubiae Iovis\edindex[persons]{Manubiae Iovis} tres creduntur esse, quarum unae sint minimae, quae moneant placataeque sint. Alterae quae maiores\edindex{maiores} sint, ac veniant cum fragore, discutiantque aut divellant, quae a Iove \AAp{sint}{sint}{}{lacuna post sint ind. Porson\edindex{lacuna}}, et consilio deorum mitti existimentur.
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledchapter*{bla}
\pend\pstart
Maeson\edindex[persons]{Maeson} persona comica appellatur, aut coci, aut nautae, aut eius generis. Dici ab inventore eius Maesone comoedo\edindex[persons]{Maeson comoedus} , ut ait Aristophanes Grammaticus\edindex[persons]{Aristophanes Gram.}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

%\printindex
%\printindex[persons]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrew Swann said, it was a bug in eledmac. I have just published on CTAN a correction for these three bugs.

Thanks a lot @Andre Swann and @mxordn.

Answer (score 3):

I think some bugs have crept in to the latest version of `eledmac` (`eledmac 2014/08/15 v1.12.3`).  In any case, the error you found disappears if you load the `hyperref` package.  However, one then gets a new error caused by index entries containing spaces.  This is correctable by writing an extra pair of brackets

```
 \edindex[persons]{{Manubiae Iovis}}
```

but that is surely not the intended behaviour (the error comes from the `xstring` parsing used by the package).  Finally even with these two points accounted for, `makeindex` will now reject three of the four entries in the `persons` index on the second run.  I think you should be report this to the maintainers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[ngerman,latin]{babel}

\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\footparagraph{A}
\footparagraph{B}
\footparagraph{C}

\newcommand{\AAp}[4]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\Afootnote{#3 \textit{#4}}}}
\newcommand{\BAp}[4]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\Bfootnote{#3 \textit{#4}}}}
\newcommand{\CAp}[4]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\Cfootnote{#3 \textit{#4}}}}

\makeindex[title=Allgemeinindex,columns=2]
\makeindex[name=persons,title=Index of names,columns=2]

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledchapter*{blabla}
\pend\pstart
Manubiae Iovis\edindex[persons]{{Manubiae Iovis}} tres creduntur esse,
quarum unae sint minimae, quae moneant placataeque sint. Alterae quae
maiores\edindex{maiores} sint, ac veniant cum fragore, discutiantque
aut divellant, quae a Iove \AAp{sint}{sint}{}{lacuna post sint
ind. Porson\edindex{lacuna}}, et consilio deorum mitti existimentur. 
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledchapter*{bla}
\pend\pstart
Maeson\edindex[persons]{Maeson} persona comica appellatur, aut coci,
aut nautae, aut eius generis. Dici ab inventore eius Maesone
comoedo\edindex[persons]{{Maeson comoedus}}, ut ait Aristophanes
Grammaticus\edindex[persons]{{Aristophanes Gram.}} 
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\printindex
\printindex[persons]
\end{document}
```

produces a persons index with only:

[image: Sample output]

under `pdflatex -shell-escape`.  The `persons.ilg` reports

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2014] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file persons.idx....
!! Input index error (file = persons.idx, line = 2):
   -- Illegal Arabic digit: position 2 in 2R.
!! Input index error (file = persons.idx, line = 3):
   -- Illegal Arabic digit: position 2 in 3R.
!! Input index error (file = persons.idx, line = 4):
   -- Illegal Arabic digit: position 2 in 3R.
done (1 entries accepted, 3 rejected).
Sorting entries...done (0 comparisons).
Generating output file persons.ind....done (5 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in persons.ind.
Transcript written in persons.ilg.
```

Comment: indeed, that is a bug. I am working on this in https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/198

Comment: @Maïeul Very good.  Thank you for the work you put in to this package.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for the possible workaround. I'll try it out. @Maïeul: If I can help something (like testing…), just tell me. I'm interested in getting a deeper look at it.

Comment: Juste send a message on the github page. I will ask you when test will be need.

Comment: @Maïeul I wasn't expecting `{}` to be a final solution, just a work around in the given cases.  As I mentioned the error is thrown by the `xstring` parsing, but could be caused by something else.

Comment: @mxordn please try the branch "issue198" on github, and send comment in the github account

Comment: @mxordn : any answer?

Comment: Sorry, just getting back to the issue. But I'm not able to open or to see, what you've committed on github (the link above returns a 404).

Comment: sorry, look to https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/198 and to the branch "issue198". Read this file to understand how I works to make debuging in eledmac https://github.com/maieul/ledmac#debug

Comment: Thanks I just had to get used to how github works. Thanks for having solved this so quick!

Comment: correction just published on CTAN. Thanks both of you.